# uploading images from iPad to a bucket in S3?

Tags: ipad, amazon-s3, image-uploading

I am writing a web app in HTML5 that is supposed to run on iPads.
I would like to upload images from the iPad directly to a S3 bucket.
If that is not possible, I can settle for uploading to my server and then I'll store it on S3 myself.

I've seen on the net that the preferred tool is SWFUpload, but I fear it wont work on iPads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you're out of luck.  Apple block file uploads in iOS Safari.  The browser doesn't have access to the iOS file system or photos.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4104/is-it-possible-to-upload-files-to-a-website-from-safari-on-iphone

You'll see if you go to Facebook's Mobile Web app  http://m.facebook.com and try to post a photo, they tell users to email the photo to a custom email address.

If you want photo uploads you'll have to find another route to upload or use an iOS application.

Comment: wow that's messed up. I could understand blocking downloads, but uploads? anyways thanks for the response.

Comment: This answer is outdated. Safari now allows file uploads, but S3 appears to require an alternative file upload method that is still not supported for Safari on iOS devices.